# How can I check whether a product exists in the cart with the same productId?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String, required: true, default: 'placeholder.jpg' },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    cart: [
      {
        product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
        quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

I want to check if a there exists a product with a same productId that I want to add to the cart. If there exists one, I want to increase the quantity.

```
export const addToCart = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { productId, quantity } = req.body;

  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).select('cart');
  if (user) {
    const productInCart = user.cart.find((item) => item.product === productId);
    if (productInCart) {
      productInCart.quantity += quantity;
    } else {
      user.cart.push({ productId, quantity });
    }
    await user.save();
    res.json(user);
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error('User does not exist');
  }
});
```

This is the code for the function. However this isn't working and separate documents are getting added instead of the quantity getting increased.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with the above code lies in the following line

```js
const productInCart = user.cart.find((item) => item.product === productId);
```

here, item.product is a Mongoose ObjectId object that you are comparing with a string. Tough both have same values but they are different objects in the heap and since you are using `===` javascript compares data types too.

you can either use `==` instead of `===`

```js
const productInCart = user.cart.find((item) => item.product == productId);
```

or you can use the `.toString()` method on ObjectId object and compare it with another string, that is the `productId` received in req.body

```
const productInCart = user.cart.find((item) => item.product.toString() === productId);
```

Yet another solution is to use `.equals()` method to compare

```
const productInCart = user.cart.find((item) => item.product.equals(productId));
```